# Return the first value that contains a substring in each row of a panda dataframe

Tags: python, search

```
list = [['apple', 'orange', 'pear'],  ['peach', 'apple', 'pear']]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print df

Out[172]: 
       0       1     2
0  apple  orange  pear
1  peach   apple  pear
```

I am trying to get the first match of the substring 'pe' for each row of df. Essentially i want the output to be a dataframe that gives:

```
       0
0  pear
1  peach
```

Please provide a feasible solution for this.

Comment: Please please please, don't do `list = [ ... ]` because now you are *shadowing the built-in `list` type constructor*. This can lead to hard-to-detect bugs down the road, and is all-around a bad idea.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Brute-force approach:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
       0       1     2
0  apple  orange  pear
1  peach   apple  pear

In [23]: def startswith(prefix, default=''):
    ...:     def f(S):
    ...:         for val in S:
    ...:             if val.startswith(prefix):
    ...:                 return val
    ...:         return default
    ...:     return f
    ...:

In [24]: df.apply(startswith('pe'), axis=1)
Out[24]:
0     pear
1    peach
dtype: object
```

Note, this is not going to be efficient. It is essentially a bulky, nested, python-for-loop. Maybe if you have a bunch of strings, a DataFrame is not the right data-structure.

Note, `df.apply` takes a *function* that will be applied to every colum (if you pass axis=0, the default value) or to every row (if you pass axis=1).

The `startswith` function is a *function factory*, so you can pass it a prefix you want to search for, and a default value that will be returned if it never finds a match (which you can set to whatever you want), and it *returns a new function* which searches the rows given these constraints.

Comment: I tried  df.apply(lambda x: x if x.contains('pe') else np.nan, axis=1) , this does not seem to work. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Swarnar because the function you pass to `apply` get's passed a `pd.Series` that is either a row or column (depending on the axis parameter). Note, I used the parameter `S` to keep that in mind. `pd.Series` does not have a `.contains` method

Comment: @Swarnar also, I think I misinterpreted your intent to look for strings that *start with* `"pe"`, but you can easily modify the above to look for strings that *contain* `"pe"` but using `if prefix in val:` instead of `if val.startswith(prefix)`

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same solution as @juanpa.arrivillaga. As long as you expect the multidimensional list input to be relatively small, then this nested loop should work just fine.

Loop through the multidimensional array (before it gets put into a DataFrame), then search through that list to find the first occurrence of a string that starts with 'pe' (or whatever you are searching for). Insert that string as a one-item-list into a result list. After populating that list, put it into a DataFrame again.

myList = [['apple', 'orange', 'pear'],  ['peach', 'apple', 'pear']]
resultList = []

```
for row in myList:
    for fruit in  row:
        if fruit.startswith('pe'):
            resultList.append([fruit])
            break

df2 = pd.DataFrame(resultList)
printdf
```